# GetMapping to Method in Spring Boot not working as required when last attribute is having . (dot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I am using SpringBoot with Maven to read JSON files, However GetMapping is not working as expected.

The expected URL is http://localhost:8081/TestResults, where TestResults is a JSON file [TestResults.json] in the provided directory path.

Currently, the below code only works when I add '.json' to the GetMapping value. Please help me understand what is wrong with my code.

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/{fileName}.json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

The above code forces me to use the URL http://localhost:8081/TestResults.json, which is not what I want.

Here's my full code:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SssApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SssApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
class FileController {
    private final String directoryPath = "C:\\Users\\Hello\\Documents\\Demo";

    @GetMapping(path = "/{fileName}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getFile(@PathVariable String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("fileName:" + fileName);
        System.out.flush(); // Flush the output to ensure it is displayed in the console

        String fullFileName = fileName.endsWith(".json") ? fileName : fileName + ".json";
        System.out.println("fullFileName:" + fullFileName);
        System.out.flush(); // Flush the output to ensure it is displayed in the console

        File file = findFileRecursively(new File(directoryPath), fullFileName);
        System.out.println("file:" + file);
        System.out.flush(); // Flush the output to ensure it is displayed in the console

        if (file != null && file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("file:" + file);
            System.out.flush(); // Flush the output to ensure it is displayed in the console

            try {
                System.out.println("file toPath:" + file.toPath());
                System.out.flush(); // Flush the output to ensure it is displayed in the console
                byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                headers.setContentLength(fileContent.length);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(fileContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Internal Server Error");
            }
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("File not found");
        }
    }


    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile() {
        // Handle file upload logic here
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("File upload successful");
    }

    private File findFileRecursively(File directory, String fileName) {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isFile() && file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)) {
                    return file;
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    File foundFile = findFileRecursively(file, fileName);
                    if (foundFile != null) {
                        return foundFile;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.5.2</spring-boot.version>
    <gson.version>2.8.7</gson.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: its working after updating spring-boot.version to 2.6.0 using "/" at end i.e. @GetMapping(path = "/{fileName}/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE). However, with inbuilt java httpServer I can access directly as required. so it needs to analysed why behavior is different.  \n InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(port); HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(address, 0); // Set up the context for file requests server.createContext("/", new MyFileHandler(directoryPath)); // Start the server server.start()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Springboot:

1. the URL example/first/second results in evaluating firstValue = “first” and secondValue = “second”
2. when using the example/gallery.df/second.ar URL, we'll have firstValue = “first.df” and secondValue = “second”
3. with the example/first.df/second.com.ar URL, our variables will be
   firstValue = “first.df” and secondValue = “second.com”

As we can see, second is always truncated.

Possible solution:

**Use Regex:**

```
@GetMapping("/example/{firstValue}/{secondValue:.+}")
```

**End with Slash:**

```
@GetMapping("/example/{firstValue}/{secondValue}/")
```

For more related details please [refer](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-pathvariable-dot).

Comment: This is not working. 

@GetMapping(path = "/{fileName}/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

However, if pass any value other than "/" its working. but I need use that value in URL. For Example : @GetMapping(path = "/{fileName}a", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

then URL will http://localhost:8081/TestResultsa

Comment: its working after updating spring-boot.version to 2.6.0 using "/" at end i.e. @GetMapping(path = "/{fileName}/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE). Thanks Gaurav.

Comment: Slash at the end is not a resource but a collection.